# PHP file upload Error 4. Works fine with small files.

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload, upload

I have a situation with a PHP file upload form. It works fine with small files. I am using PHP 5.4 and Godaddy for hosting.

The form (after simplification) is:

```
 <form id="fileupload" style="position:relative;" target="iframe_fileupload" 
   action="http://www.athiyoga.org/testupload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <input type="hidden" name="<?echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix");?>" value="first"/>
   <input type="file" name="file_1">
   <button type="submit" >Start Submit</button>
 </form>
```

The following PHP.ini params are all set to 10M:
 upload_max_filesize,  post_max_size, memory_limit.

When I try to display $_FILES, I get error = 4. Other fields are blank. If the file is small, it works great. The big files are in the range of 5MB to 6 MB. Anything less than 100KB works fine.

There is a lot of additional code as I try to display progress bar, do validation, etc. But the problem I have for now has to do with file size.

What or where else should I be looking. HOPEFULLY THERE ARE NO TYPOS while presenting the cut-down code. Mind you, all's well with small files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may need to increase these 3 values in your `php.ini`: `memory_limit`, `upload_max_filesize`, & `post_max_size`. `memory_limit` should be higher than the `post_max_size`.

Comment: This screams 'post_max_size'

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php for the translation between error numbers and meanings.

Comment: Value: 4; No file was uploaded.

Comment: All the values are significantly higher than the size of the file I am trying to upload.

Comment: have you found out the solution ? because I am also suffering from the same problem !

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but since Google brought me here, here is the two possible reasons for that :

1. You possibly have a following input file type field with the same name
2. You possibly have nested fileupload forms (or form in a form)

Error code 4 means that nothing was uploaded at all. If it is a configuration issue relative to file_size, post_max_size, etc. it will throw an error.